# spring boot YAML default and environment variable override like HOCON files

Tags: spring-boot

Is there a way in spring-boot YAML file to do the same as in HOCON files where you can have a default and be able to override it with an environment variable like this:

```
basedir = "/whatever/whatever"
basedir = ${?FORCED_BASEDIR}
```

In this case in HOCON if you don't define a environment variable named FORCED_BASEDIR then basedir will be "/whatever/whatever" but if you do then the value of basedir will be whatever is defined in the environment variable.

Thanks

So based on webdizz answer below I looked up a little bit and I found a pretty good description in book "Spring Boot in Action". Here is the hierarchy:

> There are, in fact, several ways to set properties for a Spring Boot application. Spring
>   Boot will draw properties from several property sources, including the following:

1. Command-line arguments
2. JNDI attributes from java:comp/env
3. JVM system properties
4. Operating system environment variables
5. Randomly generated values for properties prefixed with random.* (referenced
   when setting other properties, such as `${random.long})
6. An application.properties or application.yml file outside of the application
   Licensed to Thomas Snead  58 CHAPTER 3 Customizing configuration
7. An application.properties or application.yml file packaged inside of the
   application
8. Property sources specified by @PropertySource
9. Default properties

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring Boot provides means to define variables at many levels and your case is supported, you just need to define variable in following way:

in **application.yml**:

```
basedir: "/whatever/whatever"
```

and in environment:

```
export BASEDIR = "/another/whatever"
```

Then in runtime application will use value from environment.

For more details check this out [enter link description here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html).

Comment: actually what I am trying to do is from the command line to override this entry: spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      firm:
        common:
           brokerUrl: localhost:9092    so from your link this is supposed to work: --spring.cloud.stream.firm.common.brokerUrl=192.168.10.1:9092 supplied as command line option arguments but it does not. Do you know what is the right syntax?